# Bash saving a tr manipulated String

Tags: string, bash, replace, character

I have a small program that asks the user for its first name and last name. I need to change the last character of the given last name to an underscore(and any occurrence of it further in the String)  in the first name and last name. Also I need to change the user its first name to uppercase letters. I got this part of the code where I manipulate the given strings.

```
echo -n "Hello "
X="$X" | tr ${Y:(-1)} "_"
echo -n "${X^^}"
echo " $Y" | tr ${Y:(-1)} "_"
```

for some reason line 2: `X="$X" | tr ${Y:(-1)} "_"` doesnt save the variable like I want it too. When I for instance fill `"Cannon Nikkon"` the program returns `"Hello CANNON Nikko_"`. But when I print `echo "$X" | tr ${Y:(-1)} "_"` It prints `"Hello Ca__o_ Nikko_"`. I tried to solve it with writing `echo "${X^^}" | tr ${Y:(-1)} "_"` instead but it still returned `"Hello CANNON Nikko_"`. I figured out since n and N are not the same characters it won't change.

But why doesn't it save the variable in line 2? How do I need to approach this?

Comment: Of course line 2 doesn't; assignment statements don't produce output, so the pipe doesn't read anything. Further, you are setting `X` in a subshell which exits once the pipe is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
instead of this:

> ```
> X="$X" | tr ${Y:(-1)} "_"
> ```

You want to do this:

```
X=$(tr ${Y:(-1)} "_" <<< "$X")
```

That is, you want to write the output of `tr` back to `X`.
The original statement didn't do that at all,
it did something completely different:

1. set the value of `X` to `"$X"`
2. pipe the output of the assignment (nothing) to `tr`

The output of `tr` is printed, and it is not saved in `X`,
contrary to what you may have believed.

Comment: `^^` means uppercase every matching pattern (which if omitted defaults to `?`), so `first_initial` isn't necessary. Just use `${first^}`.

Comment: @janos Yes, thanks for the answer. I come from java and I'm new to Bash. I now understand how to save a manipulated String with tr properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct tool to make changes in strings `${//}`

```
first="jason";
echo "${first/%?/_}"     ### Using % means: "at the end of the string".
```

A full change will be:

```
first="jason";
first="${first/%?/_}"
first="${first^}"              ### Use ^^ to change all the string.
echo "$first"
```

And, asking the user will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Your first name, please: ? " first
read -rp "Your Last  name, please: ? " last
first="${first/%?/_}"
first="${first^}"
last="${last/%?/_}"
last="${last^}"
echo "$first $last"
```

Comment: Thanks I allready got the reading part. However I edited the question earlier saying that the last character found needs to be replaced and every other occurrence in the String needs to be replaced with it.